# How to access a server which has both private and public ip address

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an AWS instance in the public subnet of a VPC, which has a private address (10.0.x.x) and an EIP.  When I am on the VPN, I would like to access the server by its private address whereas when I am outside the VPN (from the internet), I would like to access it by the EIP.  How can I set this up in AWS?  I use Route 53 for the Domain Name services.

Comment: DNS configuration is off-topic for [so]. You might get help if you ask on [su]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you have configured your VPC. For Accessing instance on its private IP address via VPN, you need to have `VPN Gateway` configured on the VPC. Similarly, if you want to access the instance using its EIP, You need to have `Internet Gateway` configured on the VPC.